# IE toDataUrl() Security Error

Tags: javascript

I need to get my picture from canvas, so I get my image from Amazon S3, I have enabled Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) there and I have set croseOrigin attribute "anonymous" to img, and it works just fine for Chrome and FireFox, but on IE I get a Security error by calling toDataUrl method.

So how do I fix it ? I can't even see details on this Security error.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this security error in IE 11 by using fabric js. By npm install fabric or CDN.

```
     var fabriclib = require("fabric");
     var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
     var width = $('#chart-container').find('svg').width();
     var height = $('#chart-container').find('svg').height();
     var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
     var data = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg);
     data = data.replace(/xmlns=\"http:\/\/www\.w3\.org\/2000\/svg\"/, '');
     var img = new Image();
     var svgBlob = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'});
     var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);
     img.onload = function () {
         var canvas = new fabriclib.fabric.Canvas();
         var svgStr = data;
         fabriclib.fabric.loadSVGFromString(svgStr, function(objects, options){
                var object = fabriclib.fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
                canvas.add(object);
                 var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                 ctx.canvas.width = width;
                 ctx.canvas.height = height;
                 fabriclib.fabric.util.loadImage(svgStr, function(img) {
                             ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
                            img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
                    }, {
                        crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
                    });
                DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL({format: "png"});
            });
        }
    img.src = url;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the best way, but i have found a solution for this. Just converting the img to base64, and no error.
This helped -> [how to convert to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript/20285053#20285053)