# How add canvas.toDataURL in src

Tags: javascript, image, fabricjs, bootstrap-modal, todataurl

I want open content `toDataURL` in src of modal bootstrap for preview image png

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
  format: 'png',
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gislef/k320kL4f/1/

I try:

```
 <img src="data:">
```

That's pretty naive I know, but I am newbie in this matter

---

**EDIT**

tag img

```
  <img src="" id="UrlCan">
```

javascript

```
    var pngUrl = canvas.toDataURL();

    document.getElementById("UrlCan").src = pngUrl ;
```

This returns blank image.

In console returns:

```
src="data:image/png;base64,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"
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gislef/k320kL4f/2/

---

**SOLUTION**

```
 $('viewt').onclick = function() {
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
    format: 'png'
});

        document.getElementById("UrlCan").src = dataURL ;


   };
```

In local host it work.
In fiddle doesn't working

Thanks for any help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685698/getting-binary-base64-data-from-html5-canvas-readasbinarystring won't help? Whatever you get output of canvas.toDataURL stick it in.

Comment: I try but returns blank image, I add eg. in my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE toDataUrl() Security Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24428328/ie-todataurl-security-error)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 different problems here:

1) you have to make toDataUrl() from canvas when you click the preview button.

```
updatepreview = function() {
    var pngUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
    document.getElementById("UrlCan").src = pngUrl ;
}    
$("#previw").click(updatepreview);
```

2) you have to set up the cross origin policy for your images. As of now adding images from that example taints the canvas. Once is tainted you cannot export to dataUrl anymore.